# Format region-specific dates to dd-MMM-yyyy?

Tags: javascript, date, sharepoint

We have a local SharePoint install in which the vendor company had written a JavaScript function to parse all date fields in a given list and display them in `d-MMM-yyyy` (e.g. 24-Dec-2015) on page load. However, the date parsing would fail when a user changed their regional settings from `United States (English)` to `United Kingdom (English)`, as the date format changed from `mm/dd/yyyy` to `dd/mm/yyyy`. Likewise for other locales.

Keeping with this JavaScript solution, what is the best way to parse a date based on a dynamic locale?

Currently, I'm able to fetch the user's selected LCID and retrieve the culture code (e.g. `en-US`) and pass that to the [SugarJS](http://sugarjs.com/) library like so:

```
var currentCulture = "";

function configureCulture(){
    //To accurately retrieve user culture, scrape the Regional Settings page for LCID
    //This is a terrible hack, but couldn't find any other solution
    var regionalSettingsUrl = ctx.HttpRoot+"/_layouts/regionalsetng.aspx?Type=User";

    jQuery.ajax({ 
        url: regionalSettingsUrl, 
        async: false,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data) {
            var lcid = jQuery(data).find("select[name$='LCID'] option:selected")[0].value;
            currentCulture = LCIDUtils.getCultureName(lcid);
            },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
              //debugMessage(errorThrown);
            }
    });
}

//passedDate param is a string representation of a date
//actual date varies based on culture, so must parse appropriately
//e.g. 12/3/2014 is 3-Dec-2014 in United States 
//but 12-Mar-2014 in United Kingdom
function ApplyDateFormat(passedDate) {
    if(currentCulture == ""){
        configureCulture();
    }

    //Uses the SugarJs libary to create a date based on current culture code
    return Date.create(passedDate, currentCulture).format('d-MMM-yyyy');
}
```

Are there any better solutions? Note that this is simply for displaying a list in Standard View, and that the underlying data is not affected.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the toLocaleString / toLocaleFormat methods of the Date object. Maybe they're useful here.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString

Comment: The main issue is that I don't have a Date object to work with in the current solution. The current JavaScript is looping through an HTML table and passing the string representation of a date to the `ApplyDateFormat() ` function. So I have to find a way to parse a string to a date based on dynamic culture, whereas `toLocaleString()` operates on a Date.  Or find a way to actually get the date object in the underlying dataset (obviously ideal, but might require a lot of rework).

Comment: new Date.getTimezoneOffset() gets you your current regional settings. Depending on the regional settings, you can split the date string from the table in pieces and order the month/day fields into the correct format.

Comment: Interesting. I'm curious how that would work in conjunction with SharePoint's regional settings. Based on my previous experiences, I think there may be regional setting conflicts between SharePoint and the browser.

Comment: did you get a solution for this?